# Using C++ in iPhone app with iOS target below 5.0

Tags: c++, ios, compiler-errors

I have a `C++ headerfile` called `Database.hpp` in my iPhone app.

But when I put the iOS Target on Xcode to **4.3** I get this compilation error:

```
clang: error: invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ 
(requires iOS 5.0 or later)
```

Is there a workaround to make it work for iOS lower than 5.0?

Comment: exclude the `-stdlib=libc++` compiler flag. That's only for later versions of the LLVM/Clang toolchain. You will loose C++11 support, though.

Comment: With other words: get rid of the C++ code and replace it with Objective-C?

Comment: no, get rid of the C++11 code *(if any)*, and replace it with C++03.

Comment: Where can I delete that compiler flag? At `build phases` none of my files listed have a flag

Comment: Xcode gives strange names to compiler flags. I don't know, I don't use Xcode. Search for something like "use LLVM libc++ standard library" or whatever.

Comment: in Build Settings of project there is  Apple LLVM complier 4.2 section and some settings, maybe it can be helpful to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libc++ is Apple's new C++ standard library implementation. If you need to run on old OS versions, you need to use the old GNU libstdc++ library instead. In your project settings, change the "C++ Standard Library" setting to "GNU C++ (libstdc++)".

Comment: Don't forget to mention that you **have** to convert `.m` files to `.mm`